# Dynamics CRM swapping text of a Picklist option

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, picklist

We have one picklist to take action, want to show different text in 2 different forms. Am trying to use the same option instead of creating 2 different options/values as the behavior is exactly the same.

Form A - Permit Issued
Form B - Approved

> [image]

I referred [this](https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/12/01/javascript-control-optionset-values/) and implemented to remove the option & re-adding with same value but different text. Its displaying as expected but on selection the value reverts to original. I know this is coming from original option-set definition.

At least it should retain the newly added option till I submit right? If Product is refreshing the definition, can we stop it till submission?

> [image]

I am planning to add duplicate items with both options, show/hide required options & mimic the behavior for both options. Any other solution?

Comment: I expected it to retain the new value until it submits, but I tested and got the same result as you. I also created an entirely new value, but if you select that value (i.e. one outside the configured options), the field goes blank.  I'm starting to conclude that changing options via JS is limited to adding and removing existing options - not editing them. Another idea would be to have both Permit Approved and Issued as options, and when the form loads, remove one. But now there are two values that are really one, which you could handle when saving, i.e.: if (value == 3 || 4) value=3;

Comment: Exactly what am doing now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still unsure where CRM is caching the original text to display after selection (apart from text/value after removal of options on form load). Ended up with this below workaround as mentioned in my question.

Added both **Approved**(1) & **Permit Issued**(2) values in Entity Picklist field physically. Then on form load removed the unnecessary values. (Ex. **Approved** - removed in Form A picklist)

Then handled the save logic to assume the values are same (1 = 2).

I am open for any better solutions.