# Issue getting value from dynamic option set (picklist) using Javascript in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, optionsettype

I am upgrading a CRM 4 solution to CRM 2011 and I am having an issue with a dynamic Option Set.

I am populating the option set by calling an API from the Javascript. This returns a list of text and value options, which I then iterate through.

Firstly, I retrieve the object itself and add a static Default option to the list:

```
var varPicklist = Xrm.Page.getControl("list_name");

//Add a System Default option to the picklist
var opt1 = new Option();
opt1.text = "System Default";
opt1.value = 100000;
varPicklist.addOption(opt1);
```

I then iterate through the collection, create an object and add each one to the list:

```
//Populate the rest of the list
var ObjectList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LookupItem");
for (var i = 0 ; i < ObjectList.length ; i++) 
{
    var optValue
    var optText
    var ObjectListItems = ObjectList[i].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0 ; j < ObjectListItems.length ; j++)
    {
        var value = ObjectListItems[j].childNodes[0];
        if (ObjectListItems[j].nodeName == "Key")
        {
            optValue = value.nodeValue;
        }
        else if (ObjectListItems[j].nodeName == "Value")
        {
            optText = value.nodeValue;
        }
    }

var opt = new Option();
opt.text = optText;
opt.value = optValue;
varPicklist.addOption(opt);
};
```

As stated, this all seems to work. The Picklist gets populated with the values and doesn't error. If I stick an alert in there during this process, the correct values or labels are displayed.

However, somehow the items seem to get lost along the way. If I try to reference them in any way from elsewhere in the form, I get null back. I tried this;

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("list_name").getSelectedOption().value
```

...and this;

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("list_name").getValue();
```

Neither of which worked. I tried accessing the text as opposed to the values (just as a test) and couldn't get those either.

But when I tried the same methods with option sets which contained static options, I could access them no problem.

Any help with where I'm going wrong would be appreciated...

Comment: What I understand from your question is, you already have stored all the optionset list in a variable called "varPicklist". right ? 
Than what you want to do ? is not clear enough

Comment: No, what I'm doing is I start with an empty Option Set control on the form. Then on Form Load, the Javascript calls an API. This returns an XML object, which contains all of the options. I then loop through the options, create an Option object, and add them to the list, one at a time. Then later on in the form, I try to reference the options in the list. The problem is, I am unable to reference these options at this point.

Answer (score 2):

CRM picklist is a [weird control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513340/dynamics-crm-swapping-text-of-a-picklist-option). Though `getAttribute` and `getControl` are CRM supported DOM manipulator, not 100% compatible like you expect in dynamic options.

Until unless you have physical static options added in CRM picklist control customizations, you cannot use that by `getAttribute`.

Using `getControl`, only you are displaying your options, but its not original CRM picklist options to store in DB.

Add all the options as static, [hide/show](https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/12/01/javascript-control-optionset-values/) based on your need.

Update:

To add a new optionset value on the fly, use `InsertOptionValueRequest` to target the metadata service & execute the request. Read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509035.aspx#BKMK_InsertNewOptionLocalOptionSet)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how do I turn my dynamic options into static ones, and add them to the control? Do I need to call the API from a different part of the application and save the values somewhere?

Comment: Go to entity, edit the picklist & add all the options manually. Why do you want to do this in code? How frequently these options change? Picklist is meant to be static data (schema freeze). Lookup is for dynamic master data (tool admin can add/edit/delete) without schema changes.

Comment: We have to do this programmatically. The options won't change that often, but they could change at any time, and we don't want to have to release a new Customization when they do. I got around this by using JQuery instead of the CRM way. Thanks anyway